# Is there a way to have a usable mutable reference or similar to mutable data while still having usable ownership of said data

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm writing renderer for terminal in Rust and I hit a wall when trying to make something like layer system, but different.

I have structs `Renderer` and `Frame` with trait `CanvasLike`

```rust
pub struct Renderer {
    shown: Canvas,
    hidden: Canvas,
}

pub struct Frame<P>
where
    P: CanvasLike,
{
    pub parent: P,
    pub rel_pos: Dims,
    pub size: Dims,
}

pub trait CanvasLike {
    fn set(&mut self, pos: Dims, cell: Cell);
    fn pos(&self) -> Dims;
    fn size(&self) -> Dims;
}
```

I need a way to store some kind of mutable reference to the parent `CanvasLike`, while `Renderer` has ownership of it's own Canvases. Also there may be multiple mutable references to the `CanvasLike` from `Frames`.

I have tried to use `Rc<RefCell<dyn CanvasLike>>`, but I don't know how to keep ownership of the Canvas so that I can mutate it from the Frame. Another thing I tried was to implement `CanvasLike` for `&mut impl CanvasLike` , but I couldn't keep Frame for more than one frame (as in rendering phase).

```rust
pub struct Frame<P>
where
    P: CanvasLike,
{
    pub parent: Rc<RefCell<P>>,
    pub pos: Dims,
    pub size: Dims,
}
```

This has same problem as `Rc<RefCell<dyn CanvasLike>>`, because I don't know a way to keep the ownership inside `Renderer`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "how to keep ownership of the Canvas so that I can mutate it from the Frame".

Comment: Some way for Renderer to still have fields hidden and shown of owned type Canvas (not reference to it), but Frame could have mutable reference to the Canvas

Comment: Why not have `hidden` and `shown` of type `Rc<RefCell<Canvas>>`?

Comment: For now I changed `Canvas` to be just wrapper around `Rc<RefCell<Buffer>>` and be easily clonable, that way `Renderer` and `Frame` can both have ownership of it